# playing with a matrix

Tags: python, loops, matrix, random, generator

Im trying to write a Python class that creates a matrix of zeros, then uses a random number generator to pick spots on the matrix. It changes the zero in that spot to a one, until the matrix is all ones. Can someone critique/correct my code? (I also want the generator to check its proximity on the matrix, and try 3 times to find a spot that is 2 spots away from any ones.)

```
import random
import numpy as np
#agents is amount of agents available to fill grid
class Gridmodel():
    def __init__(self, gridsize, agents):
        self.gridsize = gridsize
        self.agents = agents 
        self.gridmodel = np.zeros([self.gridsize, self.gridsize],dtype=int)


    def foundspot(self):
        foundspot = False         
        tries = 0
        while foundspot == False and tries <= 3:
            x = random.randint(0, self.gridsize)
            y = random.randint(0, self.gridsize)
            if self.gridmodel[x][y] < 0:
                foundspot = True
        else: 
            tries += 1

    def goodspot(self, x, y):
        goodspot = self.gridmodel[x][y]
        for i in range(-1,2):
            for j in range(-1,2):

                print i, j, self.gridmodel[i][j]
```

Comment: What are seats and should foundspot just quit if it doesn't find anything after 4 tries (what should it notify the user somehow)?

Comment: oop! ya I changed the name of the class from seats to gridmodel while I was working with it. I edited the code above. ideally id like to have a diagram at each step, using matplotlib.

Comment: Weel, the code you posted does not set any spots to 1, I think you'll never found a spot, because by what you said the matrix will have 0's or 1's, but you only say that you found a spot when the value is less than 0.

Comment: Perhaps http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better place